# Android app directory structure, email files from internal storage

Tags: android, email-attachments, android-fileprovider

I have a problem. I'm currently saving pdf files in the internal storage 
/data/user/0/com.thatapp.myApp/files/JP_31072016065930.pdf

Reading it via the app is not a problem, so I'm positive it exists. I'm now trying to send the file via email. From the other questions and answers here, I gather that you need to use a file provider.

So I added the following to my manifest

```
<provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.thatapp.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/filepath" />
    </provider>
```

@xml/filepath contains

```
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<files-path name="my_pdf" path=""/>
```

My send email function is as below

```
String[] TO = {""};
    String[] CC = {""};
    Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

    emailIntent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
    emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, TO);
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_CC, CC);
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "OTP:" + fileNmStr);
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Email message goes here");
    File file = new File(fileNmStr);
    Log.i("PDF FILE", fileNmStr);
    Uri contentUri = getUriForFile(this, "com.thatapp.fileprovider", file);
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, contentUri);

    try {
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
        finish();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Email Sent.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "There is no email client installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

The File logs as /data/user/0/com.thatapp.contract/files/OTP_JP_31072016065930.pdf

When I run the code I hit the exception

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /data/data/com.thatapp.myApp/files/OTP_JP_31072016065930.pdf
```

So if from what I understand /data/user/0/ == /data/data/ , then what causes the problem? Is my filepath wrong? I also tried "files/" as the path in the filepath but have the same problem. Please help.... staring at the problem for 24hrs already

Comment: `The File logs as`.  Do you mean `fileNmStr`?

Comment: Your xml filepath should refer intern. And for the intent you have to add grand uri permissions i think.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer. How do you refer internal? I tried setting path as ".", "files/", "/"

Comment: Can you start reacting on all my questions?

Comment: Have you tried with the FIleProvider examples of https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html ?

Comment: Yes. That's where I got the base codes from

Comment: I also added permissions as so emailIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION); but still the same problem

Comment: This did the trick <files-path name="my_pdf" path="/"/> and  emailIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

Comment: Had to clean the project before it worked tho. Wierd... Thanks for the help

Comment: Nice you solved it.